# When did Spider-Man fight against the X-Men?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, x-men, spider-man

I remember reading some of my uncle's old comics a long time ago - these were from the 80s or earlier.  One scene that stands out is a scene where a bunch of Marvel heroes were in a large alien base. I seem to recall that it was abandoned and they were using it as their base at the time.

Spider-Man is crawling along the ceiling, wondering about what all the pipes are for (and notes that they make crawling on the ceiling fun or challenging, and are good for hiding) when he overhears the X-Men planning to leave the base to join with Magneto.

Spidey is detected (I think by Prof X) and proceeds to open up seven kinds of beating on the X-Men during his escape, and is about to tell Captain America what he heard when Xavier blanks out his mind.

I think Doom was involved somehow, too.

Does anyone recognize this scene?  What comic was it in?

Comment: Is this comic available online?

Comment: @AdamMosheh: [yup](https://www.comixology.com/Secret-Wars/digital-comic/20294).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This happened during the original Secret Wars limited series. Doom wasn't in this scene, though he was in other parts of the story.

Marvel Super Heroes Secret Wars; volume 1, issue 3 of 12; July 1984:

There had been friction between the X-Men and the other heroes. Rogue in particular felt the Avengers distrusted her; understandable, she had recently been a member of the [Brotherhood of Evil Mutants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_%28comics%29#Brotherhood_of_Evil_Mutants). Spider-Man had been exploring the building they were using as a headquarters, and he happened across the X-Men--Wolverine, Professor X, Cyclops, Colossus, Nightcrawler, and Rogue--discussing the situation, indicating that they were about to leave to join Magneto. Xaviar sensed Spidey eavesdropping, and he attacked them, possibly thinking he needed to do so to escape and tell the other heroes about this conversation.

Xaviar made him forget the incident before he could tell Reed Richards about this.

The same issue includes a split between Doom and Magneto; a creepy, barely-consensual makeout session between Magneto and the Wasp (after he kidnaps her); and the creation of Volcana and Titania.

Comment: In Secret Wars #3, to be exact: http://misc.thefullwiki.org/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_3

Comment: @Wilerson - Thanks, that was the info I needed to dig out the summary information without re-reading all the issues. (The writing is pretty bad, even worse than I remember.)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know their distrust was due to Rogue being an ex-member from the Brotherhood of Evil Mutants, as I read the original Brazilian edition, which was heavily edited: http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2009/10/29/comic-book-legends-revealed-231/ . Bad writing is one thing, bad editing over bad writing is terrible.

Comment: I believe it was also (in part) specifically because Rogue absorbed Carol Danvers's personality, destroying much of her life when doing so.

Comment: @Wilerson Was Storm edited out of the issue? There's a major subplot involving her and Thor during the Secret Wars

Comment: I'm pretty sure she wasn't - her appearance was explained as Beyonder "maxing out the aggression out of the contenders", so Storm got a mohawk and a personality change, and Professor X recovered the use of his legs (and these alterations, along with Spidey's black costume, were reverted at the end of the series). I can't recall this Storm/Thor subplot right now, I might dig out these issues later.

Answer (score 1):

To all who ponder the "Spidey vs Wolverine" conundrum, the answer is in Marvel Super Heroes Secret Wars; volume 1, issue 3 of 12; July 1984. Despite all of their team training, even Wolverine angrily acknowledges how easily Spidey HANDLES ALL OF THE X-MEN as he jokes at the same time. There is also a "DRAW" in one of the Spidey vs Wolverine "What If" comics. It ends with Spidey on Wolverines shoulders about to snap his neck (no adamantium there); but Wolverine reaches up and grabs the collar of Spidey's costume positioning his closed fist and unexposed blades at Spidey's throat. Wolverine says somethint like "I think we'll call this one a draw bub"

Answer (score 1):

More recently, Spider Man is part of the Avengers in the Avengers VS X-Men comics. He also appears in the Avengers VS X-Men: Versus sub-series, which pits Avenger and X-Men individuals against each other in matches; Spider Man goes up against Colossus in #2.

Comment: I'm sure he did AvX was a big event, and they'd be sure to involve their biggest non-Xman money maker.  The rest of it, though, doesn't match the situation in my question.  I bet Spidey fought an X-man or two during the Civil War, too, now that I think about it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my favorite scene in AvX is when spidey uses humor to defeat colossus and magick when they were all juiced up with the phoenix force.

Answer (score 1):

He fought the original X-Men way back in the day (I think it was right after Gwen Stacy died), but I can't remember much about it, other than they captured him and took him to meet Professor X.  It was the first time I'd ever heard of the X-Men.

Comment: Although this answers the question, it does not contain a great deal of detail to support your answer.  Try not to be so vague and do additional research

Comment: @n.Soong You don't trust him?

Comment: @AdamMosheh I did not say that, I merely am trying to enforce the rules of this site that we prefer evidence based answers.